# Transforming associative tree style array to a normal array recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I've an associative array from data source (which I don't control) like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "children": {
        "#1": {
            "count": 2,
            "children": {
                "#2": {
                    "count": 4,
                    "children": {
                        "#5": ...
                    }
                },
                "#4": {
                    "count": 3,
                    "children": {
                        "#6": ...
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's an ever-expanding tree structure using ids as keys. I would like to transform this into normal array so I can use lodash in the browser for a bit easier/faster manipulation.

The results should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "#1",
            "count": 2,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "#2",
                    "count": 4,
                    "children": [...]
                },
                {
                    "id": "#4",
                    "count": 3,
                    "children": [...]
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Transforming the objects isn't the problem but what I can't solve is how to do this recursively so that the structure doesn't get flatten and all children are under the right parent. I went through previous posts here but couldn't find anything that would help with this type of transformation.

Comment: Which ways have you tried so far?

Comment: I mainly played with trying to extract "key paths" so I could then process them from first to last creating "children" array at the process. However I couldn't figure out how to actually get those "key paths" and how to do them so that for example both #2 & #4 are still under #1 and not as two separate #1s with one children each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Object.keys (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and a recursive function, like so

```
var a = {
    "name": "foo",
    "children": {
        "#1": {
            "count": 2,
            "children": {
                "#2": {
                    "count": 4,
                    "children": {
                        "#5": {}
                        }
                },
                "#4": {
                    "count": 3,
                    "children": {
                        "#6": {}
                        }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

function convertKeysToArray(obj) {
    if (obj.children !== undefined) {
        var arr = []
        Object.keys(obj.children).forEach(function(key) {
            var child = obj.children[key];
            convertKeysToArray(child);
            child.id = key;
            arr.push(child)
        }) 

        obj.children = arr;
    }
}

convertKeysToArray(a)
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, "     "))
```

---

```js
var a = {
  "name": "foo",
  "children": {
    "#1": {
      "count": 2,
      "children": {
        "#2": {
          "count": 4,
          "children": {
            "#5": {}
          }
        },
        "#4": {
          "count": 3,
          "children": {
            "#6": {}
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

function convertKeysToArray(obj) {
  if (obj.children !== undefined) {
    var arr = []
    Object.keys(obj.children).forEach(function(key) {
      var child = obj.children[key];
      convertKeysToArray(child);
      child.id = key;
      arr.push(child)
    }) 

    obj.children = arr;
  }
}

convertKeysToArray(a)
so.log(a)
```

```html
<pre id="so"></pre>
<script>
  var so = {
    log: function (obj) {
      document.getElementById("so").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, "     ");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was sure that there's some super simple elegant solution to this and here it is. I was on the similar track but I seem to be really bad at thinking recursively.